# Does deleting a field in a content type remove the data?

Tags: entities, database, nodes

A [previously posted question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14813/how-do-i-reinstall-the-forum-module-in-drupal-7) appears to assume that the data is deleted in the database if the field is deleted in his/her forum content type.  I think that the field still exists and the data is still available if you add the field back.  I am reluctant to test this out on my current website in case I am wrong :}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the field deletes the data too.
As far as I can see, the database tables used to contain the field data are renamed, but they are emptied.

Visiting the page at admin/structure/types/manage/forum/fields, I deleted the "Forums" field used for the "Forum" content type; this is what I see watching the content of the database used for my Drupal test site, after I removed the field.

[image: screenshot]

To notice also that the "deleted" column in the "{field_config_instance}" table is set to 1 for deleted fields.

Comment: I was hoping that the data was still there for John in the other post I referenced in my question.  I just noticed you had edited the question or I would have figured you'd of pointed that out to him.

Comment: The question can still be interesting for other users that are in a similar situation.